# Repeating a section of an image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, repeat

I want take a section of a picture, for example the middle of a picure, and repeat only that section in the background of a div. Is this even remotely possible? I suppose I could do this in javascript, but that would be messy.

In theory the answer to my question should be able to take a single pixel from a picture and repeat it in a line, or as a solid background.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this in CSS?

Comment: You'll want to be using sprites then :)

Comment: sprites don't work with repeating

Comment: Most of the time I find I just need repeat-x, which lends itself perfectly to sprites.

Comment: chris166, sprites can/do indeed work with repeating. See my response below for details.

Comment: Yeah sprites are a lot more limiting than what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to achieve this effect using the CSS3 [`border-image`](http://ejohn.org/blog/border-image-in-firefox/) property.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to do this sort of thing in CSS2. Also, I don't think that you can do this via CSS sprites, because sprites don't stretch parts of your image—they just allow you to show certain parts of the image.

Steve

Comment: You can use javascript to simulate border-image on non CSS3 compliant browser. See: http://www.lrbabe.com/sdoms/borderImage/index.html

Comment: This is excellent and is exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks Steve and Legenden!

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what some here have stated, depending on the image, you CAN do this with CSS/Sprites. But that isn't always going to be the case. It comes down to the image you want to repeat, it's height/width in relation to the sprite it exists on, the direction you want to repeat it, and the size of the container you want it to repeat in.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sampsonresume.com](http://www.sampsonresume.com/labs/sprite.gif))</sub>

This sprite could be repeated on the left 100px for use in a sidebar, while the other portions could serve as buttons and roll-over states in a navigation. with a small change, you could make the repeatable portion horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross-browser solution, then currently you're out of luck, especially if you want a CSS-solution.

The only way to do it with JavaScript would be through the canvas element, but that's not supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot do this. You can however do it server-side or by using SVG graphics or Flash. Note that doing it with a plugin would not technically be a 'background-image", you'd need to position your content over the top of it.